# Using require in Homey Script

Tags: homey

Short question. (maybe a dummy one) Can i use an external package in homey script? So is using require/ import supported ? Or how do i have to configure this ?

I want to use the nmp package azure-log-analytics-data-collector-client :

const {
DataCollectorClient,
} = require("azure-log-analytics-data-collector-client");

but when running in homey script i get an error:

ReferenceError: require is not defined
at azure log analytics.js:7:5
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible unless you customize the app and install it via the CLI.

You would then have to add your dependency here and it will be available as a global.

https://github.com/athombv/com.athom.homeyscript/blob/eb92bffee1974327060fbd5c76a10f096ee24805/app.js#L433